# in this case it is better to use database or read for file to increase performance?

Tags: java, database, performance, file

This my class TagVertex contain one method  that read the tag value=string from textual file

and return it

```
    public class TagVertex extends Vertex<String> {

    @Override
    public String computeVertexValue() {
    String s = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(MyDataSource.TagList1K));

      for(int i = 1; i < Integer.parseInt(this.getVertexId().substring(this.getVertexId().indexOf("g")+1)); i++){
          bf.readLine();
      }
      s= bf.readLine();
      bf.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            this.setVertexValue(s);

    return  s;
        }
```

the method is called 1000 times ==>the file is read 1000 times too

It is better to use database instead of textual file?

Comment: personally i'd just cache the results for all files + write a piece of code to monitor filesystem changes and update the cache when files change (new java 7 api)

Comment: Can you explain more your idea ?

Comment: basically in your case vertex values are stores in a file/files. read all the file(s) and keep a HashMap of values in memory or something. assumming you have enough memory (should scale nicely to ~1M entries on most machines) its the fastest solution. now you only need to worry about the file being changed/edited - if that spossible. if its possible you need to watch the file for changes and if it changes flush and reload you HashMap. have a look here - http://e-blog-java.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-watch-file-system-for-changes-in.html

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the hard drive is always a very slow operation. Databases usually also access the hard drive, so they aren't necessarily faster. They can be even slower, because when the database doesn't run on the same system, the network latency is added (even when it runs on localhost, you have latency due to interprocess communication).

I would recommend you to read the file once and cache the value. When you need to be aware immediately when the file is changed, you could use the new WatchService API to reload the file when it was changed. [Here is a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview). When it isn't that important that changes on filesystem level are registred immediately, you could also save the time the vertex information was read from the hard drive, and only re-read the value when it's older than a few seconds.

Comment: +1 I would also cache the length of the file instead of calling `parseInt` for every line.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own in memory database like this.

```
private static final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public String computeVertexValue() {
    if (lines.isEmpty())
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(MyDataSource.TagList1K));
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
                lines.add(line);
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return lines.get(Integer.parseInt(this.getVertexId().substring(this.getVertexId().indexOf("g") + 1)));
}
```

Comment: what is the difference? 
**lines** will be created in each call of `computeVertexValues` method

Comment: `lines` is created once and only once as it is `static final`.  Once the file has something in it, the lines will not longer be empty and it won't be read again (end though this might be desirable after a change)